# cmd 2>&1 > log vs cmd > log 2>&1

Tags: linux, bash, unix, command-line, redirect

What is the difference between:

```
cmd > log 2>&1
```

and

```
cmd 2>&1 > log
```

where cmd is a command?

Which should I prefer and why?

Comment: @Joey: so they are identical? Thanks.

Comment: @Konerak: the second version doesn't redirect STDERR to log! Try it yourself with { echo 1; echo 2 >&2; } 2>&1 >/tmp/foobar

Comment: Please see [BashFAQ/055](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/055).

Comment: Why was this closed? This is shell programming.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Order matters. The way to reason about redirections is to read them from left to right and realize that redirections make streams point at the same place. They don't make streams point at each other.

What does that mean? If you say `2>&1` then you are redirecting stderr to wherever stdout is currently redirected to. If stdout is going to the console then stderr is, too. If stdout is going to a file then stderr is as well. If you follow this up by then redirecting stdout, stderr still points to what stdout **used** to point to. It does not "follow" stdout to the new location.

### Right

```
cmd > log 2>&1
```

This redirects stdout to `log` and then redirects stderr to wherever stdout is now being redirected, which is `log`.

**End result:** both stdout and stderr are redirected to `log`.

### Wrong

```
cmd 2>&1 > log
```

This redirects stderr to wherever stdout is currently being redirected, which is typically the console. Then stdout is redirected to `log`. Remember that stderr does not "follow" stdout, so it continues to redirect to the console.

**End result:** stdout is redirected to the log file and stderr is (still) sent to the console. This is almost certainly not what you want.

Comment: What if I want to append? `cmd >> log 2>&1`? Or `cmd >> log 2>>&1`

Comment: @ChocoDeveloper if you want to append, then cmd >> log 2>&1 . More reference here: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html & http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html

Answer (score 6):

```
cmd > log 2>&1
```

Redirects `STDOUT` to log and than replaces `STDERR` with the redirected `STDOUT`.

```
cmd 2>&1 > log
```

Replaces `STDERR` with `STDOUT` and then redirects the *original* `STDOUT` to log.