# Unable to execute a bash script in background from another bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, background

I have a shell script which I want to invoke in background, from another shell script. Both the scripts are bash scripts.
First script(a.sh) is something like:

```
read a
echo 'something'
read b
echo 'something else'
# some if else conditions
nohup bash b.sh 2>&1 > /tmp/log &
```

When I try to execute the above script as: `./a.sh arg1 arg2 | tee log`
, very strangely it stucks at the nohup line for the second script `b.sh` to finish whereas it should not.

But when I *just* have the following line in the script, it works as expected:
`nohup bash b.sh 2>&1 > /tmp/log &`

Please help. I can also share the exact scripts if required.

Comment: It doesn't stuck, just press enter.

Comment: No. It's stuck. By stuck I mean it waits for the second script to finish. Obviously pressing enter would insert a new line at the stdout, but it is not out of the first script.

Comment: Try this nohup command: `nohup bash b.sh > /tmp/log 2>&1 &`

Comment: It worked ! Thanks a lot. But I am still unable to understand why it was happening. And when same line was there in a separate script(which had no other line) why it worked there and not here. Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure from which script you tool it but I have provided you right syntax for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you wanted to happen:

1. The script runs and output things
2. The script runs a command in the background
3. The script exits
4. The pipe closes
5. `tee` exits

This is what's happening:

1. The script runs and outputs things
2. The script runs a command in the background, with the pipe as stderr
3. The script exits
4. The pipe is still held open by the backgrounded command
5. `tee` never exits.

You fixed it by pointing stderr to the log file rather than the pipe, so that the backgrounded process no longer keeps the pipe open.

The meaning of the order of `2>&1` and the redirect has been [explained in other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699790/cmd-21-log-vs-cmd-log-21), and [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) would have automatically pointed out this problem in your code.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I needed. Would take care of the order in future.