# Direct mongo output to a file

Tags: bash, mongodb, stdout

I have a script that automate the rebuilding of mongo db's for our servers:

```
#!/bin/sh

mongo local:host 127.0.0.1 mongodb-create-ourdatabase.js > validate.txt

mongoimport --host 127.0.0.1 --db ourdatabase --collection ourUser --file create-ourUser.js > validate.txt
```

The output of the first line when the database is created writes to file, but the output of the second line, where the collection ourUser is created outputs to screen.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

First, both calls create an empty, new `validate.txt` file. So second call clobbers first call result. I doubt that this is what you want, so you should change the second `>` by `>>` to *append* to your logfile.

Second, executables issue output through 2 screen channels: *standard output* (aka `stdout`, used for normal output, results) and *standard error* (aka `stderr`, used for warnings and errors). It is not possible to know which stream is the target by looking at the output.

To merge both streams and get all process output, you have to pipe `stderr` to `stdout` to be able to redirect, using `2&>1` (dup & close pipe 2=stderr to 1=stdout)

```
mongo local:host 127.0.0.1 mongodb-create-ourdatabase.js 2&>1 > validate.txt
mongoimport --host 127.0.0.1 --db ourdatabase --collection ourUser --file create-ourUser.js 2&>1 >> validate.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response Jean-Francois, unfortunately that did not work, but it was close. What worked was:

```
#!/bin/sh

mongo localhost:27017 mongodb-create-our-database.js 2>&1 > validate.txt

mongoimport --host 127.0.0.1 --db ourdatabase --collection ourUser --file create-ourUser.js >> validate.txt 2>&1
```

Using 2&>1 had the script looking for file 2, and I found this excellent explanation:

[Scroll down to 1st answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699790/cmd-21-log-vs-cmd-log-21)

which worked for me.